# Preload sounds played via iPhone AudioServices

Tags: iphone, audio

I built an iPhone app using AudioServices to play short sounds.  The first time a sound is played, there's a delay of half a second or so while the sound loads before it plays.  This definitely makes for an awkward user experience.

Is there a way to preload sounds for AudioServices to play, or do I need to switch to audioQueues or some other method of playing sounds?

Thanks,
Maha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well known problem. Everything in AudioServices is initialized lazily.

I think that your best choice is between Core Audio or OpenAL. OpenAL might be overkill, but it has a simple API. The oalTouch example is a good place to start.

Core Audio is a bit more raw, but it's well documented. The iPhone's OpenAL SDK is built on top of it.

Comment: Hi, Maha, how you can solve your problem..I am facing such problem through my application.. how can I solve it.. ? plz give me the suggestion my question is (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018508/how-can-i-fix-the-sound-problem-through-my-iphone-application/6018751#6018751)