# Preload *.wav with SystemSoundID?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am playing a wav file to give a little audio feedback when a button in my UI is pressed. My question is when you first press the button there is a delay (about 1.5secs) whilst the sound file "sound.wav" is loaded and cached. Is there a way to pre-cache this file (maybe in my viewDidLoad)? I guess I could do it by just playing it a viewDidLoad, but would really need to disable the audio so it does not "beeb" each time the app starts.

many thanks for and help.

gary

**EDIT_001:**
Looks like my question is a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862281/preload-sounds-played-via-iphone-audioservices) unless anyone has any new info? Maybe a way to turn the play volume down temporarily, unless the audio is cleared each time through the run loop.

**EDIT_002:**
I am currently using SystemSoundID / AudioServices:

```
-(void)playButtonSound {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *soundPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"buttonClick_002" ofType:@"wav"];
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath], &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

Comment: I think you just answered your own question. You will need to load it silently ready to be used on demand. It a similar approach to when you want a roll over image.

Comment: Do you know how I might load it silently, or play it with no audio? I will have a play it might just be a case of not calling "AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);"

Comment: I have no idea how the iphone API works. But I assume that you can load the audio into a variable of your application? I image probably can also set the volume you want a piece of audio to be played at. I very much doubt that your only options are to load and play immediately a piece of audio at full volume (set by the user of the phone of course)

Comment: How are playing the sound? The method you choose is highly relevant to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I actually found that using AVAudioPlayer allowed my to do the preload that I required using (see below) in viewDidLoad to do the preload:

```
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
```

and then using (see below) in the button methods where I needed the sound to play on demand.

```
[audioPlayer play];
```

gary

Answer (score 0):

Use `performSelectorInBackground:@selector(<A SELECTOR>)` when the view loads to load the wav file into memory. Then play the sound when needed ;)

Hope this helps!