# how can I fix the sound problem through my iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, singleton, audio

I am using Singleton in my iphone project. when I click on the sound button (I am using Singleton) for sound. when I click on the play (it will take 2 or 3 nano second) and then after the sound will play..

How can I fix this problem of sound..

Comment: you can distinguish nano seconds?! Get the president on the phone!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your audio session initialized before you play your first sound. You could do that on the

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

method.

Comment: thnx for the reply EliBud.. my question is same as this link      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862281/preload-sounds-played-via-iphone-audioservices